# max(y) and max(x) for $1 \geq xy\lceil{\log_2{x}}\rceil\times\frac{1}{100}$

Tags: logarithms, maxima-minima, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$1 \geq x\times\lceil{\log_2{x}}\rceil\times y\times\frac{1}{100}$

$x \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \geq 2$

$y \in \mathbb{Q}$, $y \geq 0$

now I can declare $max_y(x) = \frac{1}{x\times\lceil{\log_2{x}}\rceil\times\frac{1}{100}}$

But how to declare $max_x(y)$?

And how can I plot the graph?

Comment: There is no maximum: the supremum is simply $+ \infty$.

Comment: sorry, there was the wrong function...